# I can get penalty because changed my content?

Tags: seo, google-ranking

I have  this page in my site:

> www.mysite.com/companies/first-company

I show the data of "First Company"

My "First Company", change your name for "Second Company", so your new url is:

> www.mysite.com/companies/second-company

So, url

> www.mysite.com/companies/first-company

will redirect(301) to

> www.mysite.com/companies/second-company

But, a new company register in my site and wants the first url.
I can set first url for new company and notify google for update  through send a sitemap file. This update take a time(hour,days..)

While updated in google index is not executed, users can see   data of  first company in google results, but when click, user will see  data of second company.

I have a problem? my ranking can be affected?

Comment: You can always use Fetch as Google and Submit to Index options in the Search Console (webmaster tools). It may help. Keep in mind that once you use that option, the regular googlebot will fetch the page within a day or two and update the index officially. You may want to do this with both URLs.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a problem?

From a pure technical standpoint, no. Sometimes URLs have to change and sometimes you have to recycle one so a 301 won't work. From a semantics standpoint, if you have to do this then something about your model/workflow is flawed. Company names should be reasonable unique and so should the URLs. To have to recycle an old URL like you describe is not optimal so I would urge you to reconsider your naming conventions to get more uniqueness in there and avoid having to recycle a URL and lose the 301.

> my ranking can be affected?

Absolutely. If I see a snippet for company B in the SERPS and click through only to get company A information, I'm bouncing out of your site as soon as I can and I will be less likely to click on any of your links in the future. Depending on my medication levels at that time, I may be sufficiently paranoid to report you as a phishing or scam site too.

At best, you'll see your Bounce Rates going up and that alone will start to suppress you.  If this is a one-time thing once every few years, the impact may not be that noticeable. If you are doing it over and over again, see above re: your workflow is flawed.